# Poor zooming out distance field font?

Tags: libgdx

Being quite new with shaders, I was pleased when I successful(ish) managed to get a DistanceFieldFont shader working.
It seems to work great at making text look sharp when zoomed in....

[image: great zoomed in]

...but when zoomed out it looks hideous:

[image: poor zoomed out]

The text on the left is a normal LibGDX label for comparison.

The code making the material is;

```html
Texture texture = generateTexture(contents); //function generate text-texture from supplied letters

texture.setFilter(TextureFilter.MipMapLinearLinear,         TextureFilter.Linear);//Isnt this supposed to ensure smooth zoomout?

Material mat =  new Material(TextureAttribute.createDiffuse(texture), new     BlendingAttribute(1f),ColorAttribute.createDiffuse(Color.CYAN));

labelModel = ModelMaker.createRectangle(0, 0, 400,400, 0, mat);
labelInstance = new ModelInstance(labelModel); 
labelInstance.userData = MyShaderProvider.shadertypes.distancefield;
```

and the code generating the texture;

```
private Texture generateTexture(String text) {

      String Letters=text;
      Pixmap textPixmap = new Pixmap(TITLE_WIDTH, TITLE_HEIGHT, Format.RGBA8888);

        BitmapFontData data = DefaultStyles.standdardFont.getData(); //new BitmapFontData(Gdx.files.internal(data.imagePaths[0]), true);

        Pixmap fontPixmap = new Pixmap(Gdx.files.internal(data.imagePaths[0]));

        // draw the character onto our base pixmap        
      int totalwidth=0;
      int current_testedwidth=0;

        int currentX=0;

      float scaledown = 1f;

      Glyph defaultglyph = data.getGlyph(Letters.charAt(0));

      int totalheight=defaultglyph.height+9;

        Gdx.app.log(logstag,"scaledown="+scaledown);
        double lastremainder =0;
        int yp=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < Letters.length(); i++) {

            Glyph glyph = data.getGlyph(Letters.charAt(i));

            if (glyph==null){
                glyph=defaultglyph; //temp


            }


            if (Letters.charAt(i) == '\n'){

                Gdx.app.log(logstag,"______________adding line=");

                //new line
                yp=(int) (yp+(defaultglyph.height* scaledown)+5);
                currentX=0;
            }


            int cwidth =  (int)(glyph.width  * scaledown);
            int cheight = (int)(glyph.height * scaledown);

            int yglyphoffset = (int) (glyph.yoffset * scaledown);

            textPixmap.drawPixmap(
                    fontPixmap,
                    glyph.srcX,
                    glyph.srcY, 
                    glyph.width, 
                    glyph.height+1,
                    0+currentX+glyph.xoffset,
                    0+(yp+(yglyphoffset )),//+(TILE_HEIGHT - (cheight)) / 2,                        
                    cwidth, 
                    cheight);



            double newprecisepos =  ((glyph.xadvance+2)  * scaledown)+lastremainder;//glyph.width+3
            lastremainder = newprecisepos - Math.floor(newprecisepos);
            int newpos = (int) (Math.floor(newprecisepos));
            currentX=currentX + newpos;
        }


        return new Texture(textPixmap,true);

}
```

Is it supposed to look this bad?

I'll post the glsl stuff if needed, but (I think) zoom out should work better then this regardless no ? :?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Looks like maybe the Texture you are generating doesn't support mip-mapping. Setting the filter to MipMapLinearLinear is not enough. You must also create a MipMapped texture to begin with.

Comment: I was following this guide; 
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Distance-field-fonts
Which says to use mipmapping but doesnt say you need to do anything special with it.
The bitmap font was generated by Hiero, and looking at the png I cant see any mipmaps.

Comment: BitmapFont files don't specify mip-mapping. The mips are generated at run time by the Texture constructor. Make sure when you construct the Texture that you give the constructor's second argument of `true`. If you omit it, the Texture will not support mip mapping. Maybe you did this already, but I can't see your `generateTexture` method.

Comment: I believe I am doing that - see the return statement at the end of the new snippet added above. I assume it can make mipmaps from pixmaps?

Comment: Hmm, another reason might be that your glyphs have such thin lines. Try incrementally increasing the `smoothing` constant in the shader to see if it starts looking better.

Comment: I tried double and essentially no effect. Also half.
The only thing that helped was turning up the smoothing on the shader - but that prepositionally made the fonts blurry when close.
I think maybe the shader itself needs to handle the distance better :-/

Comment: Not sure what your first two sentences there are about, because I was saying to turn up the smoothing, which did work as you say. This leads me to think that the lines of your glyphs are simply too thin to look good at a small size with a distance field font. Are you generating the glyphs in Heiro?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I should have been clearer. 
According to the tutorial the smoothing constant should be linked the the line spread in Heiro (which I am using). At first I tried both increasing the smoothing constant in the shader AND altering the font output from Hiero to have matching spread.(smoothining= 0.25f / (spread * scale).
Changing them together in this way had no effect.
I then tried just the smoothing constant without touching the bitmap - so making it "smoother then it should be". This made it better from further away but much worse up close.

Answer (score 0):

Not completely satisfactory, but after looking around theres tweaks to the shader which produce better results;
http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=33612.0

Essentially you need to add supersampleing.
Oddly it seems to work better WITHOUT mip-maps.